# Something wrong when session in django is changed by JS

Tags: javascript, django, session

I am not sure it's about django, rather javascript and browser.

my view:

```
def set_lang(request, lang):
  request.session['lang'] = lang   

  # request.session.modified = True  # optional, to be pretty sure
  # request.session.save()  # the same

  return HttpResponse('ok')
```

in html, in js:

```
$.post('/set_lang', {'lang', 'EN'});   # it change session and works
location.reload()
```

somewhere while location.reload() the django session is "rollbacked" to previous state.

on chrome when I add own sleep method in js (1sec) before location.reload it works
on firefox problem exists regardless.

I do not use cookies except session one.
I tried cleanup browser cache, session, but without success.
I can repeat this on different browser versions.

I have workaround but I am curious what happened.

when I remove from js `location.reload()`, and then do POST/GET request will be handled ok with correct session.

`F5 refresh` after set_lang also works always (session is changed correctly).

I compare http headers between `location.reload` and `F5 refresh` and they are the same.

Comment: When you do `return HttpResponse('ok')` does it not loose the context?  I would try `return HttpResponse(request.session)` and see what it prints

Comment: no, set_lang works and I can return changed session, session is losing in next request  (`location.reload()` and only with this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like `location.reload` doesnt allow `$.post`

```
$.post(url, data);
// sleep(2000) // own func with timeout works only in chrome for me
location.reload();
```

I ask myself if posting have enough time to send and found solution in [jQuery.post docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

when I change code to:

```
$.post(url, data).done(function(data{window.location.reload();})
```

it works now in every browser :)